# ItoProcess with matrix of equations

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, random-process

What is the cleanest/simplest way to use `ItoProcess` to solve the equation

$$i \text{d}\boldsymbol{\psi} = H\cdot\boldsymbol{\psi} \text{d}t + \boldsymbol{\psi}^2\text{d}t + \text{d}\mathbf{w},$$

where $H$ is a matrix, $\boldsymbol{\psi}$ is a vector, $\mathbf{w}$ is a vector of random processes, and $\boldsymbol{\psi}^2$ denotes the element-wise square. The initial condition for $\boldsymbol{\psi}$ is known. Here is some initial code (but I'm looking for a general approach that treats any number of simultaneous differential equations)

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
H = RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, {4, 4}];
H = H + ConjugateTranspose[H];
psi0 = RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, 4];
process = ItoProcess["???"];
sim = RandomFunction[process, {0, 10, 0.01}]
ListPlot[Re[sim]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way I worked out how to do it. It's not pretty though.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
L = 4;
H = RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, {L, L}];
H = H + ConjugateTranspose[H];
psi0 = ConstantArray[0, L];
variables = Table[Unique["x"], {L}];
X[t_] = #[t] & /@ variables;
wVariables = Table[Unique["w"], {L}];
w[t_] = #[t] & /@ wVariables;
wiener = # \[Distributed] WienerProcess[] & /@ (wVariables);
system = I \[DifferentialD]X[
         t][[#]] == ((H.X[
            t])[[#]] \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD](w[
           t])[[#]]) & /@ Range[L];
process = ItoProcess[system, X[t], {variables, psi0}, t, wiener];
sim = RandomFunction[process, {0, 10, 0.01}];
ListPlot[Abs[sim], Joined -> True]
```